# how to know the value of bind parameter in PDO in php

Tags: php, pdo

I have following code in which I want to know the value of bind parameter:

```
$sql->bindParam( ':checkbox', $value['CHECKBOXLIST'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

How can i know value of `:checkbox` variable?

This variable i am passing to `IN` query of `WHERE` clause, but unable to get result. This is a statement. `$value['CHECKBOXLIST']` returns array like `1,2,3,4`.

where  Checkbox `IN` (:checkbox)

How can I also handle it?

Answer (score 0):

[PDOStatement->bindParam()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) stores a **reference** to a PHP variable:

> bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed
>   $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int
>   $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int
>   $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )

When you run the query, the value is read from such variable. So the value is right in that variable, in your case `$value['CHECKBOXLIST']`. If you remove or overwrite the variable before running the query, the value will be lost.